# Extjs - Ext.form.panel is not displaying the output after selecting the multi-set combo value

Tags: extjs

After selecting multicombo value while clicking on Ext.form.panel the selected multi value combo is not display in IE10

Comment: paste your code. Is it working in other browser ?  if it is only IE10 issue then please check IE compatibility issue.

Comment: Ext.define('MAILTEMPLATE',{
     extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
     alias:'widget.MAILTEMPLATE',
     labelWidth : 90,
   frame : true,
   width : (viewSize.width -220),
   buttonAlign:'center',
   dockedItems: [filterBar],

Comment: items:[{
     xtype: 'htmleditor',
              fieldLabel: 'Mail Template',
              name:'msgText',
     autoScroll:true, 
              id:'htmlApplicationEditor',
              readOnly:'true',
              disabled:false,            
              ctCls: 'html-no-border',             
              height :((viewSize.height)/2)-20,
              anchor:'100%',

Comment: listeners: {
                  afterrender: function(editor) {
                     editor.getToolbar().hide();
                     editor.bodyEl.down('div.x-html-editor-input').applyStyles({
                       'border-top-width': '1px'                          
                     });
                },                  
                 scope: this
              }    
         }

Comment: Find the above code

Comment: Can you paste your code in question.  Is it making any sense to paste code in comment ?